# How can I cancel a Task without LOOP

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation-token

Hi I've been reading alot on the forum but I'm not able to find the answer to my problem...

Here's my function that I want to cancel when a boolean turn to TRUE:

```
Task<PortalODataContext> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var context = connection.ConnectToPortal();
            connection.ListTemplateLib = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplateLibrarys(connection);
            connection.ListTemplateGrp = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplateGroups(connection, connection.TemplateLibraryId);
            connection.ListTemplates = this.ShellModel.ConnectionManager.GetTemplates(connection, connection.TemplateGroupId);
            return context;
       }, token);
```

How can I verify if the token got a cancel request without a LOOP ?

Something like that :

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled before long running task started");
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    //My operation

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        break;
    }
}
```

But I dont have an operation that require a Loop so I dont know how to do that ...

Comment: why don't you add the loop so we follow your train of thought.

Comment: Test for cancellation after every granular operation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming `token` is a `CancellationToken`?

You wouldn't need a loop, instead take a look at [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). By calling this, the `CancellationToken` class will check if it has been canceled, and kill the task by throwing an exception.

Your task code would then turn into something like:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
{
    // Do some unit of Work
    // .......

    // now check if the task has been cancelled.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Do some more work
    // .......

    // now check if the task has been cancelled.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, token);
```

If the cancellation exception is thrown, the task returned from `Task.Factory.StartNew` will have its [IsCanceled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set.  If you're using async/await, you'll need to catch the `OperationCanceledException` and clean things up appropriately.

Check out the [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) page on MSDN for more info.

Comment: So I need to verify if the token got cancel after each line?

Comment: After each unit of work that it makes sense to cancel, yes. That could be a single method call or a set of method calls.  With the example you posted, I would put a check before each of the ConnectionManager calls. It won't always be every line of code.